# avoid autopostback in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey friends i want to avoid postback on the click of image button,here is my code:-

It has a gridview with a image button for editing the row selected

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Label ID="lblsearch" Text="Search by" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsearch" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchProject" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="select" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>                        
  <asp:Button ID="btnclear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnclear_Click" />
  <asp:Label ID="lblsearchmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>
  <br />
  <asp:GridView ID="gviewprojectallocation" runat="server" CellPadding="4"
       ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" EnableViewState="true"
       AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE"
       BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
       onrowcommand="gviewprojectallocation_RowCommand"
       onrowcancelingedit="gviewprojectallocation_RowCancelingEdit" 
       onrowediting="gviewprojectallocation_RowEditing" 
       onrowupdating="gviewprojectallocation_RowUpdating">
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
       <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
       <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
       <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
       <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
       <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
       <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' runat="server" id="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" CommandName="Edit"/>
           </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="associate_id" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Associate ID"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Associate_Name" ReadOnly="false" HeaderText="Associate Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="involve_percent" ReadOnly="false" HeaderText="Involve %" />
       </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
</form>
<br />
</center>
```

code behind:-

//to load information in a dropdownlist at page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(constring);
  SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand();
  mycommand.Connection = myconnection;
  int i = 1;

  SqlDataReader mydatareader = null;
  myconnection.Open();
  mycommand.CommandText = "select Project_Code,Project_Name from Project_Status_Report;";
  mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

  mydatareader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    while (mydatareader.Read())
    {
      ddlsearch.Items.Add((string)mydatareader["Project_Name"]);
      ddlsearch.Items[i].Value = Convert.ToString(mydatareader["Project_Code"]);
      i++;
    }
  }
  myconnection.Close();
}
```

//for searching on the basis of the value selected in dropdownlist:-

```
protected void SearchProject(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand();
    DataSet mydataset = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter mydataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    if (ddlsearch.SelectedValue == "select")
    {
      Response.Redirect("ProjectAllocation.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
      mycommand.CommandText = "select P.associate_id,T.Associate_Name,P.involve_percent from Associates_Info as T inner join Associate_Project as P on T.Associate_ID=P.associate_id where P.project_code = @procode;";
      mycommand.Parameters.Add("@procode", SqlDbType.Int);
      mycommand.Parameters["@procode"].Value = ddlsearch.SelectedValue;

      mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      myconnection.Open();
      mycommand.Connection = myconnection;

      mydataadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand;

      mydataadapter.Fill(mydataset);

      if (mydataset == null || mydataset.Tables.Count == 0 || mydataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
      {
        lblsearchmsg.Text = "Record not found";
      }

      gviewprojectallocation.DataSource = mydataset;
      gviewprojectallocation.DataBind();

      myconnection.Close();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
     lblsearchmsg.Text = "Enter valid information";
  }
}
```

//row command of gridview:-

```
 protected void gviewprojectallocation_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
   {
     int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
     GridViewRow row = gviewprojectallocation.Rows[index];
   }
 }
```

//grid view row editing event

```
protected void gviewprojectallocation_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{                        
  gviewprojectallocation.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  gviewprojectallocation.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you might want to try adding `OnClientClick='return confirm_ambiguous_functionality();'` to your definition of your `ImageButton` as well as some javascript.  Or you could just simply have it return nothing (e.g., `javascript:void(0);`)  depending on the intended functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_ambiguous_functionality() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to do whatever action you just clicked on?");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Bryan its working but now the image button has to be clicked twice..to see changes

Comment: Did you view the HTML being rendered by the server?  What is causing the postback?  You might want to try just using a LinkButton instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best scenario that would go with your situation is to put your gridview in an update panel and make the whole process a partial post back, since you need the image button to go to the server since you are saying the image button is used for editing the row selected.